Get rectangular with rounded corners in ffmpeg
I want to get rectangular with rounded corners using ffmpeg commands. I assume it should be done by geq command, but I couldn't make it and couldn't find any examples.  Since I'm going to use this rectangular for blur effect I don't want other tools to be involved. Here is the command I currently have
[0:v]split=3[base][blur1_in][blur2_in];

[blur1_in]crop=w=100:h=100:x=20:y=40[region1];
[region1]boxblur=luma_radius=10:luma_power=1[blurred_region1];
[base][blurred_region1]overlay=x=20:y=40:enable='between(t,0,5)'[tmp1];

[blur2_in]crop=w=30:h=30:x=20:y=40[region2];
[region2]boxblur=luma_radius=5:luma_power=1[blurred_region2];
[tmp1][blurred_region2]overlay=x=20:y=40:enable='between(t,5,10)'[tmp2];

[tmp2]ass=../logs/ass.ass:fontsdir=../fonts/Audiowide-Regular.ttf[final_video]

Now I need to add rounded corners to this boxes.
